# How to set Crystal Report database field to grow vertical only

Tags: crystal-reports

[image: crystal report view]

I've crystal report like this. When database field grows it damages the formatting. How to set db field to grow vertical only.

Answer (score 0):

Split your *Details* section into multiple sub-sections. e.g. put `Customer` in *Details a* section, `Address` in *Details b* section and `Tel No` in *Details c* section and then enable / check `Can Grow` property for the field you want to let grow vertically only.

Comment: Thank you for answer, But adding multiple details section in this case may  not be suitable because I have many such fields on one page which is a print requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the field that grows using formulas and put them on a text field separated by blank spaces. For example, if the address might grow 3 lines, create 3 formulas(address1, address2, address3) and write inside them

```
stringvar array Address := Split({@address} , chr(13));
Address[1] //show {@address} first line

stringvar array Address1 := Split({@address} , chr(13));
Address1[2] //show {@address} second line

stringvar array Address2 := Split({@address} , chr(13));
Address2[3] //show {@address} third line
```

So you will be dividing address in 3 pieces and can put them side by side. You can do this for as many lines your address may grow.